# How to set a pandas dataframe equal to a row?

Tags: pandas

I know how to set the pandas data frame equal to a column.
i.e.:

```
df = df['col1']
```

what is the equivalent for a row? let's say taking the index? and would I eliminate one or more of them?

Many thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? if you're asking how to get just a single row then you do something like `row = df.iloc[x]` where x is some integer in your index range

Comment: that's exactly what I was asking for. I edited the question asking for how to delete this row as well. I f can you put everything in an answer that would fully close the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to take a copy of a row then you can either use `loc` for label indexing or `iloc` for integer based indexing:

```
In [104]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.random.randn(10),'b':np.random.randn(10)})
df

Out[104]:
          a         b
0  1.216387 -1.298502
1  1.043843  0.379970
2  0.114923 -0.125396
3  0.531293 -0.386598
4 -0.278565  1.224272
5  0.491417 -0.498816
6  0.222941  0.183743
7  0.322535 -0.510449
8  0.695988 -0.300045
9 -0.904195 -1.226186

In [106]:
row = df.iloc[3]
row

Out[106]:
a    0.531293
b   -0.386598
Name: 3, dtype: float64
```

If you want to remove that row then you can use `drop`:

```
In [107]:
df.drop(3)

Out[107]:
          a         b
0  1.216387 -1.298502
1  1.043843  0.379970
2  0.114923 -0.125396
4 -0.278565  1.224272
5  0.491417 -0.498816
6  0.222941  0.183743
7  0.322535 -0.510449
8  0.695988 -0.300045
9 -0.904195 -1.226186
```

You can also use a slice or pass a list of labels:

```
In [109]:
rows = df.loc[[3,5]]
row_slice = df.loc[3:5]
print(rows)
print(row_slice)
          a         b
3  0.531293 -0.386598
5  0.491417 -0.498816
          a         b
3  0.531293 -0.386598
4 -0.278565  1.224272
5  0.491417 -0.498816
```

Similarly you can pass a list to `drop`:

```
In [110]:
df.drop([3,5])

Out[110]:
          a         b
0  1.216387 -1.298502
1  1.043843  0.379970
2  0.114923 -0.125396
4 -0.278565  1.224272
6  0.222941  0.183743
7  0.322535 -0.510449
8  0.695988 -0.300045
9 -0.904195 -1.226186
```

If you wanted to drop a slice then you can slice your index and pass this to `drop`:

```
In [112]:
df.drop(df.index[3:5])

Out[112]:
          a         b
0  1.216387 -1.298502
1  1.043843  0.379970
2  0.114923 -0.125396
5  0.491417 -0.498816
6  0.222941  0.183743
7  0.322535 -0.510449
8  0.695988 -0.300045
9 -0.904195 -1.226186
```